# SerializeData in CompositeView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

I need to pass a value to the `listView.template` in order to be aware the template about the `collection.length`.
I think one option is to redefine the serializeData method in order to pass a parameter in this way.

```
var ListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.on('reset', this.serializeData, this);
        this.collection.on('remove', this.serializeData, this);
        this.collection.on('add', this.serializeData, this);
    },

    serializeData: function () {
        console.log(this.collection.length);
        return {
            has_tasks: this.collection.length > 0
        };
    },

    // other codes
});
```

---

When I start the `app` the `collection` is not yet fetched so:

1.a) the `collection.legth = 0`
2.b) the template get `has_tasks = false` as expected.

2.a) after the fetch the `collection.length is > 0`,
2.b) the `serializeData` is called and so it puts the `has_tasks = true`,
2.c) the template seems to be not rendered because it maintains the `has_tasks = false`

Any idea because `2.c`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest Marionette has solved this problem by calling an optional `templateHelpers` on the view to provide additional context to the view. Also your event binding is not Marionette-friendly as it it will not be auto-unbound correctly when the view is unloaded. So all you need to do in your view is:

```
var ListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.bindTo(this.collection, "add", this.render, this);
        this.bindTo(this.collection, "remove", this.render, this);
        this.bindTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render, this);
    },

    templateHelpers: function () {
        console.log(this.collection.length);
        return {
            has_tasks: this.collection.length > 0
        };
    },

    // other codes
});
```

Note, however, that you probably don't want to rerender the entire view and all the sub-elements every time an item is added or removed. A better approach is to only update the count displayed. For instance:

```
var ListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.bindTo(this.collection, "add", this.updateCount, this);
        this.bindTo(this.collection, "remove", this.updateCount, this);
        this.bindTo(this.collection, "reset", this.updateCount, this);
    },

    updateCount: function() {
        this.$('.count_span').html(this.collection.length);
    },

    // other codes
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use something like:

```
var ListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.bindTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render)
  },
  serializeData: function () {
    return { has_tasks: this.collection.length > 0 }
  }
});
```

Calling serializeData again will have no effect on your view. You need to render it again in order to show the new values (because `render` will get the data by calling `serializeData` again).

Anyway what is the point of sending `hasTask` to the template since you can access the collection (and thus its length)?

Comment: The point of sending hasTask is to display the template section regarding the case when `hasTask = false`. Should I make something different? IMH the CompositeView template have no access to collection but just the model attributes. The item has access to collection. Am I right?

Comment: You can check that by `console.log(this)` from your composite view template. As I don't use the same stack as you, I can't be sure of what you have.

Comment: The CompositeView has access to collection but `marionette.composed.view` renders the `model.attributes` no the collection.

Comment: You could reference the collection in the model (it's what Backbone Relational does).

Comment: Thanks, this is a smart idea...I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Another way to pass data from the collection view to its children is to use the `itemViewOptions` method (or attribute). Be careful: it requires Marionette 0.9.x and Underscore 1.3.3. More documentation on https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-itemviewoptions.